# What is the meaning of the notation "$j_1(x|a_i|\alpha_i)$"?

Tags: polynomials, notation, euclidean-algorithm

I'm reading Dehn's *Algebraic Equations*. On the second of these two pages:

> [image]
>
> [image]

There is the notation "$j_1(x|a_i|\alpha_i)$", but I can't figure out what it is. I guess I understand the subject from previous exposure in lectures and also from reading these pages, but I never saw this notation used before nor know what it means.